# Create two-way relationship list properties on class (Employee-Job)

Tags: c#, .net

Currently I have two classes, one is Employee, the other is Job.

Job has a binding list of Employees and both are a subclass of INotifyPropertyChanged

At this stage, Employee also has a binding list of Jobs.

Each time I create a job, I add employee's to it. Then for those employees I add the jobs.

This is where things go pear shaped, the situation becomes infinitely recursive.

It seems wrong for each object to have a binding list of their occupancy. Perhaps I should just pass some sort of reference, Like in the case of the Jobs list of employees I could pass their name, or vice versa.

Any suggestions are welcome.

here is my current code: (NOTE: This version is attempting to using AddingNew events. Which I think I'm doing incorrectly)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Assignment_3
{
    public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        static readonly object _object = new object();
        private string name_;
        private string returnString_;
        private Occupation occupation_;
        private decimal rate_;
        private BindingList<Job> employeeJobs_;

        public event AddingNewEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public BindingList<Job> employeeJobs
        {
            get
            {
                return employeeJobs_;
            }
            set
            {
                employeeJobs_ = value;
                makeJobList();
            }
        }

        public void makeJobList()
        {
            //PropertyChanged(jobList, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("jobList"));
            returnString_ = "";
            foreach (Job currentJob in employeeJobs_)
                returnString_ += currentJob.jobNumber.ToString() + " ,";
        }
        public Employee(BindingList<Job> employeeJobs, string name, Occupation occupation, decimal rate)
        {
            employeeJobs_ = employeeJobs;
            employeeJobs_.AddingNew += new AddingNewEventHandler(employeeJobs__ListChanged);

            name_ = name;
            occupation_ = occupation;
            rate_ = rate;
            makeJobList();
        }

        private void employeeJobs__ListChanged(object sender, AddingNewEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, e);
            }
            makeJobList();
        }

        public string name
        {
            get
            {
                return name_;
            }
            set
            {
                name_ = value;
            }
        }

        public Occupation occupation
        {
            get
            {
                return occupation_;
            }
            set
            {
                occupation_ = value;
            }
        }

        public decimal rate
        {
            get
            {
                return rate_;
            }
            set
            {
                rate_ = value;
            }
        }

        public string jobList
        {
            get
            {
                makeJobList();
                return returnString_;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The  Job code is pretty much the same.

```
private void createNewEmployeeButton__Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindingList<Job> selectedJobs = ExtensionMethods.MakeBinding<Job>(jobsForNewEmployeeBox_.SelectedRows);
    MessageBox.Show(selectedJobs.Count.ToString());
    Employee newJoe = new Employee(selectedJobs, nameTextBox.Text, (Occupation)occupationComboBox.SelectedItem, rateNumericUpDown.Value);

    foreach (Job job in selectedJobs)
    {
        job.employees.Add(newJoe);
        job.makeEmployeeList();
    }

    employeeList_.Add(newJoe);
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: *the purpose of having the occupancy as a property is so I can have it as a field in the datagridview.

Comment: I seem to have solved the infinite recursion issue by excluding PropertyChanged calls in the case where it is a listChangedType.ItemChanged

Comment: A better solution seemed to be turning the RaiseListChangedEvents = false while calling the PropertyChanged event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you factor out the relationship to its own class? Instead of having an instance of a list of Employees in the Job and vice versa, you'd have only one list. This one list can never go out of sync - a problem that you inevitably have when you have separate lists on all Jobs and Employees objects.

### EmployeeJobAssignment class

This class contains a reference to an Employee and a Job object and depicts the relationship between them.

### EmployeeJobAssignmentCollection class

This class publishes an `ObservableList<EmployeeJobAssignment>` as a property and also offers methods that allow to change the registered relationship, i.e.:

- SetEmployeeJobs(employee, collection of jobs): removes all assignments for an employee and adds the new assignments.
- SetJobEmployees(job, collection of employees): removes all assignments for a job and adds the new assignments.

Of course, you can define other methods so like AddEmployeeToJob that only asserts that a specific relationship is present and adds it if required.

The `ObservableList<EmployeeAssignment>` that is published by the class asserts that other classes can register to be notified when changes to the relationships are made.

### Employee/Job classes

When you instantiate an Employee or a Job object, you hand it a reference of the EmployeeJobAssignmentCollection object. The newly instantiated objects subscribe to the CollectionChanged event of the `ObservableCollection<EmployeeAssignment>`. This way, they are notified abount changes. 

The classes keep their collection properties of Jobs or Employees respectively and ask the EmployeeAssignmentCollection to return the relevant objects based on their own id. 
Once the object is notified about a change in the relations, they also signal that there was a change in their collection of Jobs or Employees. You might want to implement a mechanism that verifies whether the change is relevant to a specific Employee or Job in order to avoid unnecessary events.

**UPDATE**: In order to signal the change to the bindings of Jobs/Employees, the easy way would be to raise a PropertyChanged event for the collection properties. As an alternative, you could also return a collection that implements INotifyCollectionChanged. This can be an `ObservableCollection<Job>` or `ObservableCollection<Employee>` respectively. Downside is, that you'd need to sync these collections whenever a change in the EmployeejobAssignmentCollection occurs. You can also implement a "fake" collection that implements INotifyCollectionChanged and passes through the Jobs/Employees based on the contents of the EmployeeJobAssignmentCollection that are relevant for an Employee or Job respectively. The effort for this would be higher as you'd need to be able to discern whether items have been added or removed. **END OF UPDATE**

If the classes need to change the Jobs or Employees, they call the `SetEmployeeJobs` or `SetJobEmployees` methods. The related objects are notified through the events. As they also rely on the EmployeeJobAssignmentCollection, they do not need to change a list and by that trigger `CollectionChanged` events by themselves.

Also you need to make sure that the Jobs and Employees unregister their handlers by implementing `IDisposable`.

### Putting it all together

- When you set up your data, you also create and set up the EmployeeAssignmentCollection. It should at least contain the relationships of the relevant Jobs and Employees.
- Next, you create the instances of Jobs and Employees and provide the EmployeeAssignmentCollection.
- Use the objects as before.
- Dispose of the objects as soon as you don't need them anymore.

Hope this rough outline of the model helps. If not, let me know in the comments.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your great synopsis of how to go about this. I'm having trouble with using the appropriate interfaces however. Also having issues with editing the Job/Employee in their datagridview. I think the CollectionChanged event is not getting triggered. Possibly because I am not passing it on to the appropriate handlers.

So, EmployeeJobAssignmentCollection, contains an ObservableCollection<EmployeeJobAssignment>

does it require to be a subclass of INotifyCollectionChanged?

Comment: @LostMinty: no, INotifyCollectionChanged is implemented in the `ObservableCollection<EmployeeJobAssignment>`. I've updated my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'm caught on your wording here:

Comment: Thanks, I'm caught on your wording here:
" When you instantiate an Employee or a Job object, you hand it a reference of the EmployeeJobAssignmentCollection object. " 

by reference, I understand that by default (?) the EmployeeJobAssignmentCollection is a reference to the data contained within? that being a colleciton of references to EmployeeJobAssignment objects, which in turn contain references to pairs of Employee-Job references.

Comment: I am confused as to why when I update say a Employee.Name via the datagridview, that when I access it in the Job's reference of EmployeeJobAssignmentCollection it is out of date?

Comment: @LostMinty: as to the wording: you have one EmployeeJobAssignmentObject and you provide that to the Employees and Jobs as a constructor argument. To the update problems: you should make sure that there is only one edition of an Employee/Job for an id, so that each change is done on the same instance.